# Typescript : Import module only if condition true else skip checking module present

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am running tests using jest.
I am modifying a library(lib) to use it in my package. This lib requires a module that cannot be installed from my package. So, I have introduced a cmd line argument to import the module only when arg is set to true
I am implementing something like this

Original Sample.test.ts

```
import {testLib} from "../lib"

await new testLib().func(args);
```

lib.ts

```
const client = require("test-module") // this is the module thats not present
await this.client.set(args);
```

Modified Sample.test.ts

```
if(process.env.NEED_LIB === "true"){
    const testLib = import("../lib");
    await new testLib().func(args);
```

But I am getting this error:
`This expression is not constructable. Type 'Promise<typeof import("lib")>' has no construct signatures.`

I am not sure how else to use the library(`lib`) in my package
I tried other variations but I kept getting `Module not found` error.
Basically I want TS to skip checking module is some condition holds true
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to learn the operator precedence in JavaScript. `await` has a lower precedence than call `()`. Parenthesise the expression, as in `new (await testLib)().func(args)`, or await the import which is far far more readable

Answer (score -1):

I just modified

```
const testLib = import("../lib");
```

to

```
const testLib = require("../lib");
```

and the error is gone

Comment: Instead of fundamentally changing the meaning of your code and making it compatible with a different subset of module loaders, just fix your syntax